# Could Barman backup only one database from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman, patroni

In my system, I have postgresql 12 and barman v2.13. I have a few backup disk around 1 TB and i have currently added new DB which has 5 TB. Previously my PostgreSQL had no more than 400 GB.

i think Barman can not compress backup DB, right? So could i take backup only specific DBs? Is pgbacktress similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barman transparently uses *pg_basebackup*, so you can't backup only a specific database, as *pg_basebackup* works at the cluster level.

Barman **can** do compression of WAL files, but not of the base backup.